# Why does the do-while loop not run as expected in this Java program?

Tags: java, do-while

I've been writing a program that will take an array of the names of music files and play them. I succeeded in doing that, but, I wanted to touch up on some things and make it a little nicer. I am trying to make the music play in a random order but not repeat any songs before the entire list has been played. I was almost able to do it but I think there is something wrong with my do-while loop. The program runs as intended for about eight songs but then it stops playing the music and the JVM continues to run. I am using BlueJ as I am still an AP Comp Sci student so I realize that I might not be able to accomplish this task but any help would be greatly appreciated. I have a driver, "MusicDriver" that is a "has-a" relationship with two other classes: "MP3" and "Music".

my MP3 class:

```
import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import javazoom.jl.player.Player;

public class MP3 {
    String filename;
    Player player; 

    public void stopMP3() { if (player != null) player.close(); }

    // play the MP3 file to the sound card
    public void playMP3(String filename) {
    try {
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(filename);
        BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(fis);
        player = new Player(bis);
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Problem playing file " + filename);
        System.out.println(e);
    }

    // run in new thread to play in background
    new Thread() {
        public void run() {
            try { player.play(); }
            catch (Exception e) { System.out.println(e); }
        }
    }.start();
}  
}
```

my Music class:

```
import java.util.*;

public class Music{
private ArrayList<String> music;

public Music(){music = new ArrayList<String>();}

public int size(){return music.size();}

public void addSong(String song){music.add(song);}

public String getSong(){return music.get(music.size());}

public String getSong(int num){return music.get(num);}

public void removeSong(String song){
    for(int i = 0; i < music.size(); i++){
        if(music.get(i).equals(song)) {music.remove(i); return;}
    }
}

public String toString(){
    String s = "";
    for(int i = 0; i < music.size(); i++){
        s += music.get(i);
    }
    return s;
}
}
```

my MusicDriver class:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
import javazoom.jl.player.Player;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;

public class MusicDriver{
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException{
    Random r = new Random();
    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    String line = "";
    int number;

    Music song = new Music();
    song.addSong("1-01-overture.mp3");
    song.addSong("1-03-fortune-teller-2.mp3");
    song.addSong("1-07-prayer.mp3");
    song.addSong("1-08-island-atlas.mp3");
    song.addSong("1-12-warren-report.mp3");
    song.addSong("1-13-avilla-hanya.mp3");
    song.addSong("1-20-war-situation.mp3");
    song.addSong("2-10-fog-of-phantom.mp3");
    song.addSong("2-12-religious-precepts.mp3");
    song.addSong("2-14-box-of-sentiment.mp3");
    song.addSong("3-02-light-everlasting.mp3");
    song.addSong("3-09-viking-spirits.mp3");
    song.addSong("3-12-unsealed.mp3");
    song.addSong("3-16-notice-of-death-reprise-.mp3");
    //14 songs

    ArrayList<Integer> songNums = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    MP3 mp3 = new MP3();
    do{
        if(songNums.size() == song.size()) songNums.clear();

        number = r.nextInt(song.size());
        boolean done = false;
        int counter = 0;
        while(!done){
            for(int i = 0; i < songNums.size(); i++){
                if(number == songNums.get(i).intValue()) {number = r.nextInt(song.size()); counter++;}
            }
            if(counter == 0) done = true;
            else done = false;
        }

        songNums.add(number);
        mp3.playMP3(song.getSong(number));
        System.out.println("Now Playing " + song.getSong(number));
        System.out.println("Enter \"Stop\" to stop playing the song");
        System.out.println("Enter \"n\" to play the next song");
        line = s.nextLine();
        mp3.stopMP3();
    }while(line.equals("n"));
    mp3.stopMP3();
}
}
```

I have done a lot of research on why my program just stops playing my songs but I haven't been able to find anything. I did, find that BlueJ programs don't open the terminal window (the thing that comes up when you do a "System.out.print()") if you ask for input before you have any output but I don't think that comes into account for this program. I have also made sure that I have input a String "n" when I want to play the next song and for the first couple songs, it works, but after the eighth song, it just stops. I am thoroughly confused.

Comment: just [`Collections.shuffle()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#shuffle-java.util.List-) the list and play songs one by one in for-each loop

Comment: Is it compulsory to invoke stopMP3 before the do-while loop ends? I suspect a possible cause of premature stoppage there.

Comment: Are you getting any exceptions by chance?

Comment: and seems you need some kind of synchronization (in order to query for input after a song is finished). Now the `MP3#playMP3()` is not blocking, so it returns right after the song is started (when, I suppose, you don't need to ask "Play next?")

Comment: @SashaSalauyou: That is one of the reasons, I thought mp3.stopMP3 could be a problem. payer is released without the status of the current song. (Not sure if that could be an issue)

Comment: @SendhilkumarAlalasundaram I believe the main problem here is in lack of understanding what methods should be blocking, what should not, how do they run in threads and how to synchronize all this stuff properly

Comment: Could u be entering into an infinite loop? I suggest you do what @SashaSalauyou said...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think the only issue lies in the logic that you are using for shuffling the list.

```
number = r.nextInt(song.size());
boolean done = false;
int counter = 0;
while(!done){
    for(int i = 0; i < songNums.size(); i++){
        if(number == songNums.get(i).intValue()) {number = r.nextInt(song.size()); counter++;}
    }
    if(counter == 0) done = true;
    else done = false;
}
```

When the random number generated is already existing in the songNums list, you are generating a new random number. This new random number is not checked with all numbers of songNums list. The following change should solve your problem.

```
    boolean done = false;
    while(!done){
        number = r.nextInt(song.size());
        if(!songNum.contains(number)) done = true;
    }
```

*Alternatively, you can use [Sasha](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3459206/sasha-salauyou)'s suggestion in the comments for shuffling the list(Collections.shuffle()).*

Answer (score 3):

The actual problem with your existing algorithm is you are not resetting `counter` when you discover a song that has already been played. So as soon as you hit a repeat, you get stuck in an infinite loop - `done` will never be true.

(Actually, it won't be infinite - once `counter` reaches `Integer.MAX_VALUE` it will wrap around to `Integer.MIN_VALUE` and eventually reach `0` again, so if you left it long enough it would eventually play another song)

There are some useful suggestions here already about improvements to the code and I won't repeat them here, but the minimum change that will fix what you have is to move the initialization of `counter` to `0` inside the loop:

```
boolean done = false;

while(!done){
    int counter = 0; // reset counter every time

    for(int i = 0; i < songNums.size(); i++){
        if(number == songNums.get(i).intValue()) {number = r.nextInt(song.size()); counter++;}
    }

    if(counter == 0) done = true;
    else done = false;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Sasha said it in the comments:  use Collections.shuffle().  In practice that would look a lil' something like this:

In the Music class have a method to get all the songs:

```
public List<String> getSongs() {return music;}
```

The loop in MusicDriver would be along the lines of:

```
List<String> songs = song.getSongs();
do{
    Collections.shuffle(songs);
    for (String songToPly: songs) {
        mp3.playMP3(song.getSong(number));
        System.out.println("Now Playing " + song.getSong(number));
        System.out.println("Enter \"Stop\" to stop playing the song");
        System.out.println("Enter \"n\" to play the next song");
        mp3.stopMP3();
        line = s.nextLine();
        if (!line.equals("n")) break;
    }
}while(line.equals("n"));
```

On a variable-naming note, naming the instance of your Music class as "song" (singular) is kind of confusing.  Maybe call it "music" or at least "songs".

Answer (score 0):

What I would do is:

```
public class MainClass() {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        PlayerWrapper player = new PlayerWrapper();
    }
}

public class PlayerWrapper() {
    private List<MP3> playlist;
    private Scanner userInputReader;
    private String currentUserInput;

    public PlayerWrapper() {
        userInputReader = new Scanner(System.in());
        System.out.println("Filepath to playlist?");
        String playlistFileName = userInputReader.nextLine();
        playlist = PlayListExtractor.extractPlaylist(playlistFileName);
        start();
    }

    public void start() {
        playlistCopy = new ArrayList<MP3>(playlist);
        shufflePlayList(playlistCopy);
        Iterator<MP3> songIterator = playlistCopy.iterator();
        while (songIterator.hasNext()) {
            MP3 song = songIterator.next();
            songIterator.remove();
            player = new Player(song.toStream());
            player.play();
            displayCurrentSongAndCommands(song);
            currentUserInput = userInputReader.nextLine();
            if ("Stop".equals(currentUserInput )) {
                player.close();
                break;
            } else if ("n".equals(currentUserInput )) {
                player.close();
                continue;
            }
        }

        if("Stop".equals(currentUserInput)) {
            System.out.println("Playlist stopped. Press q to quit or c to continue");
            currentUserInput = userInputReader.nextLine();
            if ("q".equals(currentUserInput)) {
                System.exit(0);
            } else if ("c".equals(currentUserInput)) {
                start();
            }
        }
        start();
    }

    private void shufflePlayList(final List<MP3> playlistToBeShuffled) {
        long seed = System.nanoTime();
        Collections.shuffle(playlistToBeShuffled, new Random(seed));               
    }

    private void displayCurrentSongAndCommands(final MP3 currentSong) {
        System.out.println("Now Playing " + currentSong.toString());
        System.out.println("Enter \"Stop\" to stop playing the song");
        System.out.println("Enter \"n\" to play the next song");
    }
}

public static class PlayListExtractor() {
    private PlayListExtractor();

    public static List<MP3> extractPlayList(final String playListFileName) {
        List<MP3> result = new ArrayList<>();
        try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file))) {
            String line;
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                result.add(new MP3(line));
            }
            return result;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Problem parsing playlist");
        }
    }
}

public class MP3 {
    private String filename;

    public MP3(final String filename) {
        this.filename = filename;
    }

    public BufferedInputStream toStream() {
        try {
            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(filename);
            return new BufferedInputStream(fis);                  
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Problem playing file " + filename);
            System.out.println(e);
        } 
    }

    public String toString() {
        return filename;
    }
}
```